# Section numbers as drop caps in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, scrbook, drop-cap

I'm trying to work out a way so that when I use `\section` it will typeset the section number as a drop cap. I can do this using a custom macro as shown in the below MWE, but I was trying to get it done using the built-in KOMA-script customization mechanisms.  But I can't seem to work out how to do it, and every way I've tried (using sectionformat and putting the `\lettrine` call in there) produces errors and an invalid document.

Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be, and I should just use my own `\sec` macro to get this?  I'm planning on using running headings, do I need to do something other than `\refstepcounter{section}` in my macro for the running headings to work?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
fontsize=8pt,
letterpaper,
twoside,
draft,
BCOR=1in,
DIV=13,
parskip=half-,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\sec}{\refstepcounter{section}\lettrine[lines=3,findent=1ex,lraise=0.20,grid=true,]{\thesection}{}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\sec{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you mentioned running heads: Why you are using `\chapter*` instead `\addchap` or at least `\addchap*`? Additionaly there are no section titles which could be displayed in the header, only the section numbers? So for me it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I'm only using the section numbers and the chapter title in the running head. I didn't bother putting all the running head examples in here so as not to dilute the issue of this particular question.  I only mentioned running head, because the normal sectioning commands that make the automatic running head need to continue to work with whatever I end up with.

Comment: But `\chapter*` does not set a running head. Is there a table of contents too?

Comment: The particular chapter command in the example isn't really the focus of the question, but I've changed the code to use `\chapter` to remove that distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a new command instead of redefining the math operator `\sec`. Additionally it is not really a section so I would use a different counter. If this should be used in running heads you have to set `\markright`.

```
\documentclass[%
fontsize=8pt,
letterpaper,
twoside,
draft,
BCOR=1in,
DIV=13,
parskip=half-,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{dcsec}[chapter]
\newcommand{\dcsec}{%
    \par
    \refstepcounter{dcsec}
    \markright{Number \thedcsec}
    \lettrine[lines=3,findent=1ex,lraise=0.20,grid=true,]{\thedcsec}{ }%
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\dcsec
\lipsum[1-2]
\dcsec
\lipsum[4-30]
\end{multicols}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\dcsec
\lipsum[1-2]
\dcsec
\lipsum[4-30]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```